# How to make a static singleton copy of an immutable constant object in Net core controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a typical .NET Core Controller that has some methods that would retun an empty object of certain type as a reply if something went wrong. E.g.

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        // The object in question. We return it if something is went wrong in any of the methods.  
        private readonly ReplyObject emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCases = new ReplyObject(); 

        [HttpGet]
        public ReplyObject GetStuff()
        {
          if (someProblem) return emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCases;
          // more business logic...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ReplyObject GetOtherStuff()
        {
          if (someOtherProblem) return emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCases;
          // more business logic...
        }
        // List of methods goes on
    }
}
```

I am new to .NET Core and is not yet fluent in a threading model involved with controllers, e.g. how many instances of Controllers are usually created.

Question: what additional declaration I should give to the emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCasesto have one (or just a few instances) of it created, ever? E.g., is "static" enough to reach the goal? Or perhaps there is some other way to create such an immutable singleton and reuse it in controllers?

Comment: Since the object is `readonly`, `static` is what you search for.

Comment: You lost me. if it's constant then why mutability matters? if it's immutable then why do you need a copy of it?

Comment: About controller instances, there will be one for each request. They will be part of the `Scope` lifetime of the `IServiceCollection.AddScoped`. Your `ReplyObject` however could be registered as `AddSingleton` as a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line:

```cs
private readonly ReplyObject emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCases = new ReplyObject();
```

to this:

```cs
private static readonly ReplyObject emptyReplyObjectForInvalidCases = new ReplyObject();
```

Then you'll only ever have one instance of it for the life of the application.